# stored procedure Working in MSSQL But Not working in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, stored-procedures

When I call a stored procedure through PHP it does not show the results, but when I run this code in Management Studio it shows a full result. Here is the code of my PHP (Codeigniter):

```
public function get_current_mon_att($data)
{
    $emp_id = $data['emp_id'];
    $start_date = $data['start_date'];
    //$query = $this->db2->query("EXEC Sp_att_full @StartDate = N'$start_date', @emp_id = $emp_id");
    $qrystring = "DECLARE   @return_value int EXEC  @return_value = [dbo].[Sp_att_full] @StartDate = N'$start_date', @emp_id = $emp_id SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value";
    $query = $this->db2->query($qrystring);
    echo $qrystring;
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: Do you expect `return $query->result();` to return the results of multiple queries, or the last query? Maybe try removing the `SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value` piece.

Comment: i have only executed only `EXEC Sp_att_full @StartDate = N'$start_date', @emp_id = $emp_id` but result is same.

Comment: Well, this function only returns the result, you also then need to tell PHP what to do with the result. Have you looked at any code that already functions?

Comment: `public function get_remaining_lv_balance($data)
    {
        $emp_id = $data['emp_id'];
        $lv_id = $data['Leave_id'];
        $query = $this->db2->query("EXEC sp_LeaveBalance $emp_id, $lv_id");

        return $query->row();
    }`

Here is the function which is already working in php.

Comment: That function is not "already working" on its own. Something is calling that function, and then doing something with the result. That's the part you need to emulate.